# How do I set from address in embark tests

Tags: solidity, unittesting, embark

In my embark tests, I have the following tests:

```
it("should allow setting new beneficiary by owner to valid address", async function () { 
        //await UTO.setBeneficiary(0x0, {from: owner}).should.be.rejectedWith(EVMInvalid);
        await UTO.setBeneficiary(owner, {from: customer});
        (await UTO.beneficiary()).should.deep.equal(owner);
     });
```

'customer' maps to a valid address. The contract is:

```
pragma solidity >=0.6.0 <0.7.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Pausable.sol";

contract UTO is ERC20, Ownable, Pausable {

    string private _name = "UnlimitedToken";
    string private _symbol = "UTO";

    uint256 public tokensPerEth;            //Number of tokens per ETH
    uint256 public tokenValue;              //Value of 1 Token (in ETH)
    uint256 public percentForBeneficiary;   //Percentage of tokens generated to be assigned to beneficiary
    address public beneficiary;             //The address of the beneficiary of the held tokens

    constructor(address _beneficiary, uint256 _tokensPerEth, uint256 _percentForBeneficiary) ERC20(_name, _symbol) public {
        tokensPerEth = _tokensPerEth;
        tokenValue = 1 wei;    //initial value, dynamic once contract is deployed
        beneficiary = _beneficiary;
        percentForBeneficiary = _percentForBeneficiary;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Allows the current owner to change the beneficiary.
     * @param newBeneficiary The address of the new beneficiary.
     */
    function setBeneficiary(address newBeneficiary) public onlyOwner {
        require(newBeneficiary != address(0), "Invalid address for beneficiary");
        beneficiary = newBeneficiary;
    }

}
```

So the function call to setBeneficiary should only be allowed to be called by the owner of the contraact. However, the from address is ignored and the test passes. I have replaced the from address with invalid data as well with the same result. So, it seems that setting **{from: 0xaddress}** is ignored.. any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "the test passes"? There is no test here, just a function-call which may be a transaction or perhaps just an RPC (we don't know because you haven't posted the code of that function).

Comment: I have edited the question to include more code for clarity. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So the problem seems to be an incompatibility with the old way of doing things with web3js and the latest version of embark (5.2.3)...

The following works as expected:

```
await UTO.methods.setBeneficiary(owner).send({from: customer});
```